# jQuery Form Plugin - utf-8 chars with file upload not working

Tags: jquery, content-type, jquery-forms-plugin

With the help of [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) we are uploading a file along with regular form fields. Everything was working fine.
But if there is any utf-8 special characters then it is converted into some junk characters server side.
When request header was inspected we found that in content type charset=utf-8 was missing. Tried adding the content type while submitting but nothing helped.

```
 var options = {
         success:       successfunc,
         contentType: 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8',
 };
 $("#formid").ajaxSubmit(options);
```

After analysing the jQuery script file we found that

```
  var s = $.extend(true, {}, $.ajaxSettings, options, {
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         cache: false,
         type: 'POST'
     });
```

If the content type in the jQuery was altered then server code is unable to get the request parameters due to boundary value problem. Is it not possible to upload the file and send utf-8 special characters in a single ajax submit?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue I believe.  I am calling a .Net asmx service and it will not return JSON to me, I believe because of this option.  I made a simple AJAX request to my service without the form plugin and the service returns results as expected.  Have you made any headway with this?  Thanks for th post.